# Bypass "Pick an account" prompt when logging on

Tags: sharepoint-online, login

Is there a way to bypass the "Pick an Account" screen if the user is currently signed on? We have SSO and executives are complaining about having to click to pick an account from below screen before they could access the site. I've tried Smart Link but not really sure I did it correctly because each time I click the link, it would still redirect me to pick an account.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your SSO isn't working as it should. Since this isn't a SharePoint Online topic (SPO is just a victim), but rather an Active Direcotry/Azure AD topic, ServerFault or similar might be a more appropriate network.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Clear IE cache.
2. Reset IE settings. Go to IE->internet options->advanced tab->reset.
3. And then add the site into trusted site and select “Automatic logon with current username and password” in IE.
4. When logging into the site in SharePoint online, select “Yes” like the picture below.

[image]